# Book series with a cover of a girl with unusual eyes, who receives a crystal ball

Tags: story-identification, novel, young-adult

Don't really remember any of the books because I don't remember ever fully finishing the first book.

All I remember is the cover was beautiful! There was a young girl on it with really pretty eyes. Can't remember the color but it was an unnatural color. 
I believe it's a Sci-Fi teen series. I remember something about a crystal ball maybe and she had a very unique name that I believe was also the title of the book.

It was early 2000s. I remember being in elementary school when I found it. I'm 21 now. I'm thinking the eyes might have been purple. But could have been a green or blue also. I remember the crystal ball thing that she got it on her birthday or some special day. It's supposed to help her with her future. I honestly didn't read the whole book probably only the first couple chapters but it was so long ago. I just remember the cover is why I got it. The girl on it was so pretty and the cover colors and everything I just wanted to have it.

It's not these books:

*The Messenger* - Carol Lynch Williams
The cover of that book reminds me of the one I'm looking for. The writing might be the exact same or close. The coloring style of it is the same. The difference is the girl. The girl in the one I'm looking for is younger then the girl on this one. Her hair is down and the eyes are of course colored.

Definitely not *Alanna* or *Avielle* as answered.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! This doesn't offer much to go on, though. Can you remember any other details like when it might have been written, what decade you read it, etc.? If you don't remember the color, can you describe which color it was closest to? Any information you can think of helps.

Comment: It was early 2000s I remember being in elementary school when I found it. I'm 21 now. I'm thinking it's might have been purple. But could have been a green or blue also. I remember the crystal ball thing that she got it on her birthday or some special day. It's supposed to help her with her future. I honestly didn't read the whole book probably only the first couple chapters but it was so long ago. I just remember the cover is why I got it. The girl on it was so pretty and the cover colors and everything I just wanted to have it.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. I've edited the information from your comment into your question post. If you have any additional information that you think of later, please [edit] that into your post. The edit button is also in the lower left corner of your question post.

Comment: Well I also am pretty much 100% sure the title of the book was the name of the girl

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note that Goodreads also lists a book from the author entitled "Evie Messenger" although there's no book cover.

Comment: No that's not it . It was a one word title and was also the name of the Main character. Thanks though:)

Comment: You might have a bit more luck if you give some more details about the girl on the cover.  Was her hair dark or light? Her skin color? Did she look slightly Asian,  or very Slavic? Practically all girls on covers are pretty, so that ain't much.

Comment: [Alanna](http://d.gr-assets.com/books/1386131302l/19169208.jpg)?

Comment: @Richard She definitely has purple eyes... though that's a new cover I've never personally seen. Looks like it may be from 2007?

Comment: @Catija - Earliest publishing was 2004

Comment: Alanna does indeed have purple eyes but she isn't given a crystal ball. She finds a crystal attached to the hilt of a (magic) sword, but it can't be used for scrying.

Comment: Nope so far no of this is it...

Comment: @JohnRennie: Just to clarify, the crystal was not initially attached to the sword. It was an ember that the Goddess provided in a vision that she put on a chain. She indeed does not use it for scrying though, although she does look through it in the first book to see through illusions.

Answer (score 8):

Was it *Zenda and the Gazing Ball* (2004) by Ken Petti?

> The biggest day of Zenda’s life is finally here: In a few short hours she will be presented with her very own gazing ball. It is the gazing ball that will reveal her thirteen special “musings,” the lessons unique to Zenda that will guide her on her journey through life.

The crystal ball is featured on the cover:

[image: Glittery cover depicting a brune-hairedgirl and a glowing ball]

Higher quality images aren't available of this cover, but if it were enlarged you may be more clearly able to see the bright blue eyes you can find on some of the other covers:

[image: girl wears a crown of flowers] [image: Girl on a purple/pink background]

I was actually looking for the exact book, well what I think is the same book, when I stumbled upon this post. But, I think what the asker is looking for, and the book I was thinking of, is the second book in the series.

Here's the cover of the second *[Zenda](https://www.goodreads.com/series/71056-zenda)* book, *Test of Mirrors*. This is the one that I read a long time ago, and was trying to figure out the title of when I stumbled upon your post!

I read it when I was younger, and the details the asker remembers are the exact ones that I remember as well.

Comment: Aside from the cover, what makes you think this a match? Could you [edit] in some details about the book?

Comment: While that's undoubtedly a very pretty girl on the cover, her eyes are not her most striking feature.

Comment: I've edited the information from your other answer into this one since it looks like you intended to edit this answer. Welcome to SFF.SE!

Answer (score 3):

**Avielle Of Rhia** by Dia Calhoun? 2006. She's given a crystal swan in the second chapter.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1007276.Avielle_of_Rhia):

> With her silver skin and silver hair, fifteen-year-old Princess Avielle of Rhia resembles her Dredonian great-great grandmother who practiced evil magic. Everyone in Rhia expects Avielle to turn evil, too. Shunned by those around her, she feels unloved and unable to love others. In addition, she fears that Rhia will go to war with Dredonia, which suffers under the rule of evil wizard-priests: the Brethren of the Black Cloaks. They have placed impossible demands upon Rhia, but the king and queen have refused to acquiesce. One terrible night, the Brethren attack, killing the royal family and hundreds of others. Only Avielle escapes. She must keep her identity secret to avoid death from the enemy. While hiding among the common people, she learns that she has a magical gift for weaving. But will this gift, rooted in her Dredonian blood, lead Avielle to the same evil that possessed her great-great grandmother? Or will it help her free her people from further attacks.?

[image: blue cover art with a female face]

Comment: HAHA.. I answered an ID question with this same book a few weeks ago.

Comment: Nope not it a younger girl

Answer (score 1):

[*I Am Morgan Le Fay*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/606935.I_Am_Morgan_le_Fay) (2001) by Nancy Springer!

The main character has a unique name, also the title of the book.  Her eyes are two colors,  purple and emerald green.  The OP stated they read the book in the early 2000's, *I am Morgan Le Fay* was published in 2001, and could probably be found at many school book fairs (that's where I bought my copy).  Lastly, the main character finds a small  blue "druid stone" in the 2nd chapter (the OP's so called crystal ball).

Comment: Hi there. Could you please [edit] in the parts that make you think it's a match, or at least a summary? The purpose of this site is not to have people having to do more research to see if that was the right book or not. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be thinking of *The Fallen Star* by Jessica Sorensen.

For eighteen year-old Gemma, life has never been normal. Up until recently, she has been incapable of feeling emotion. And when she’s around Alex, the gorgeous new guy at school, she can feel electricity that makes her skin buzz. Not to mention the monsters that haunt her nightmares have crossed over.

[image: "The Fallen Star" book cover]

Comment: Welcome to [Science Fiction & Fantasy SE](/tour)! Please consider [registering your account](/users/login), which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your posts if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. [Registering](/users/login) is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see [Why should I register my account?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/162827)